# How can I create a shared library in Jenkins with both arguments and a body?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries

Basically I want to create a shared library in Jenkins which turns:

```
kPod(label: label){
    body
}
```

into:

```
podTemplate(label: label, //use argument as label
containers: [containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp', image: 'someImage', args: '${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}')],
volumes: [hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')]) {
    //put body here
}
```

However all the examples I see either allow you to access the arguments OR the body, but not both. The doc has no mention of it either: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

But it clearly is possible since the podTemplate step itself is doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol, I just needed to add it as a param:

```
def call(config, body) {
    // config is a map of the parameters
}
```